# I am not able to load username from database in JavaFX combobox

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-8

This is the UserController.java class.

```
public ObservableList<UserModelItem> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 @FXML
 private ComboBox<UserModelItem> combo;
This is the UserModelItem.java.class

public static class UserModelItem{
        private final SimpleStringProperty username;
        public UserModelItem(String user){
            super();
            this.username = new SimpleStringProperty(user);
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username.get();
        }
        public void setUsername(String uname){
            username2.set(uname);
        }
    }
```

This is the initialize method in UserController.java.class

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
combo.setItems(options);
}
```

This this the FXML reference to the ComboBox-

```
<ComboBox fx:id="combo" layoutX="131.0" layoutY="377.0" onAction="#fillComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" />
```

This fillComboBox() function is assigned to ComboBox with fx:id combo via SceneBuilder along with the UserController class.

```
public void fillComboBox(ActionEvent event){
            try{
                Connection connect = SqLiteConnection.Connector();
                String query = "select username from employee";
                PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                options.add(new UserModelItem(rs.getString("username")));
            }
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the function to convert ObservableList to String-

```
    combo.setConverter(new StringConverter<UserModelItem>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(UserModelItem object) {
                return object.getUsername();
            }

            @Override
            public UserModelItem fromString(String string) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
}
```

I have checked most of the answers on stackoverflow and my code is identical to those still I am not able to populate the ComboBox.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the element of your FXML file which refers to `fillComboBox`.

Comment: @VGR i have added the FXML reference to combobox. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ComboBox’s action is triggered whenever the user selects a new value.  Initially, the ComboBox has no items, so a selection is not possible and the user cannot trigger an action, which means `fillComboBox` is never called.

I’m guessing it was not your intent to have the ComboBox refresh itself only when the user changes its value.  You probably should remove the `onAction` and just call `fillComboBox` directly from within your `initialize` method.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but your suggestion worked. I just removed the onAction event associated with combobox and called the fillComboBox() function in initialize method and voila....... it worked.... a billion thanks to you. have accepted your answer....